# Headings from Grid Column Values

Tags: grid, sort, title

Is there a method where I could generate a heading using a grid column value?

My grid is output as a table sorted by the column “sport” with values like “hockey, baseball, soccer” etc.

So as I loop through the different sports, I’d like a heading for each. So when it shows the entries sorted with the value ‘hockey’ there would be a heading ‘Hockey’ displayed. Any thoughts on doing that?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this. You add a grid field for the heading value, then when you input data ensure that field is only present in the first row of a group.

The template code would then go something like this:

Lets say your grid name is sport_grid, and the grid has two field, grid_heading and grid_item

```
{sport_grid}
{if sport_grid:sport_heading}<h1>{sport_grid:sport_heading}</h1{/if}
{sport_grid:sport_item}
{/sport_grid}
```

So what the tenplate is doing is only outputting the heading if it exists.

Comment: Works, thanks! One of those things when you see it you slap your forehead and say "of, course".

Comment: Actually that doesn't quite work, now that I've added more data. It just spits out the heading title for as many rows their are in the grid. So if I have 10 entries, it shows the header 10 times then shows the data below.

The idea is I have grid:

Comment: If I have a grid:  
PlayerName  Number  Sport  
  
I want to output:  
  
Sport (Heading)
---
PlayerName  Number        
PlayerName  Number        
PlayerName  Number     

Sorry hard to show without linebreaks.